# Host WCF service with Transport security with Certificate authenticating in IIS7 (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to host a WCF service which is using "Transport" security and "Certificate" as Client authentication in Windows Server 2008 R2 and I am getting the following error:

"The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'SslNegotiateCert'"

I hosted the same service in IIS 7.5 in Windows 7 and it is working fine. I am not able to understand if I am missing anything in this environment.

Here is my web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TestService.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">


    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestService.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="TestService_Client2_ITestService" />                               
  </service>                    
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">           
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />                            
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>        
</behaviors>  
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>                

    <binding name="TestService_Client2_ITestService">             
        <security mode="Transport">

              <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>         
    </binding>          
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Below is the setting I did in IIS:

1) Hosted the webservice as an website
2) Installed the server certificate
3) Enabled Https and assigned the port and also assigned the certificate
4) In website-->SSlCertificates-->Accept is enabled (also tried with both Accept and Require SSL) didnt work.
5) Application Pool Identity:.net 4.0, Enable 32 bit: true

While searching for this error, I found the below hotfix from microsoft which was part of .net framework 3.5.1. So i installed .net framework 3.5.1 feature in windows server 2008 R2,  but still no luck.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976566

Currently, I ran out of ideas and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By this `4) In website-->SSlCertificates-->Accept` did you mean `SSL Settings`?? to be clear, in SSL Settings of the website you need to check the "Require SSL" checkbox and below that for client certificate you should choose either "Accept" or "Require". Other than that everyting seems alright, did you use another browser to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Ashkan, My bad it is SSL settings. I tried both options in 1) SslSettings->Require Ssl (checked) & Accept (Checked) and 2) SslSettings-->Require Ssl (unchecked) &Accept (checked). for both the variations it didnt work. On that server box there is no other browser installed other than IE. I am not sure if I am allowed to install other browsers...but I dont think even that will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, after I changed my security mode from "Transport" to "TransportWithMessageCredential" and passed the clientAuthentication in Message layer rather than in Transport. Below is the config change:

```
<binding name="TestService_Client2_ITestService">             
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">

          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
    </security>         
</binding>
```

I am not sure why, but for some reason in Windows server 2008 R2, passing certificates through transport layer is not working (or) may be there is a setting which I need to turn ON. It would be great to know the root cause.